# Pressing more than six keys simultaneously with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keyboard-events

While working on a simple game, I've noticed that when I have six keys on the keyboard pressed down simultaneously, catching the keydown and keyup events on the document of the web app starts to get unpredictable. With the following code snippet, the keys being listed stop showing up after six keys and sometimes less are kept pressed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Keyboard test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="target"></div>

<script>

var target = document.getElementById('target');
var keyInventory = {};
var REFRESH_RATE = 1000 / 60;

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  keyInventory['Key code ' + e.keyCode] = false;
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  keyInventory['Key code ' + e.keyCode] = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  target.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(keyInventory).replace(/,/g, '<br />');
}, REFRESH_RATE);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the browser blocking some combinations or does the browser draw the line at six with the 'keyup' and 'keydown' events? Is there some default behaviour that needs to be prevented? Is it the same for all browsers? Is there a way to allow more than six of any key combinations to register?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your keyboard that has a limit on simultaneous keypresses?

Comment: You seem to be right! My mac Keyboard Viewer also handles only six keys at a time. I didn't expect it to be an OS problem. I remember playing two-player games on the keyboard on much older computers... although now I question my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with your keyboard. IIRC, USB can only support 6 simultaneous key-presses. (Not USB keyboards, I mean *literally* the USB protocol). Because of this limitation, many consumer keyboards also only support 6 simultaneous keys.

If you want more than that (aka N-KRO) you will need to buy a keyboard that supports that and also most likely use PS/2. Because, aside from weird hacks to the USB protocol, PS/2 is the only thing that supports infinite key-presses.

So actually your memory is probably correct. Since most keyboards used to be all PS/2 they all (theoretically) could support N-KRO.

Comment: Since this turns out to be a hardware issue rather than a JavaScript or browser problem, this should count as a solution.